# How would you say 'I take [---] lessons'?

Tags: translation, word-choice, phrases

How would you say 'I take ~ lessons'? Such as dance lessons, swimming lessons, Chinese lessons, etc.

Can you say「水泳の授業をします。」　or 「水泳の授業に通っています。」? And do all of the above examples have the same structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb to say "to take a lesson" is (授業を)**受ける**. You can say 水泳の授業を受けています, for example. 水泳の授業に通っています is also okay, but it's closer to "I go to swimming classes".

水泳の授業をします would mean giving a swimming lesson rather than taking it.